# How to show actual email address in iOS Mail app?

Tags: ios, contacts, mobile-mail

iOS: 12.2

In the iOS Mail app, if the sender or recipient of an email has more than one email address associated with it, how can I tell which specific email address was used? For example, if I send myself an email from my personal account to my work account, since they're both associated to the same contact, I can't figure out how to tell who the recipient actually was. I have both Short Names and Prefer Nicknames turned off in the Contacts preference.

Comment: Can you tap on the name in the email to show the address?

Comment: No, it just brings up the Contact showing multiple email addresses

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. If you see the word 'Details' at the top of the message (near the right side), tap it.
2. Click on the persons name to open the contact card
3. Scroll to their emails
4. Look for the email with a "recent" tag above it.<sup>*</sup>

<sup>*</sup>In older iOS versions the correct email/phone number had a different color but in new versions it has a "recent" tag above the correct email/phone number.

See below:

[image]

Comment: A caveat here is that you'll need to be in the 'Details' view for this to work.   If you see the word 'Details' at the top of the message (near the right side), tap it.  This will allow you to tap the sender name to view more information (tapping the sender name wont work if not in that view).  If you see the word 'Hide' at the top, you are already in the details view.

Comment: @Apple - give us the choice to show email addresses in-line please. It does not feel trustworthy to be looking at a contact card and believe that "recent" actually genuinely relates to a specific, single email - from where I accessed the contact card - when it could relate to any of hundreds of emails.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be correct on iOS 15.3.1 (the current version). I do not see a details page, nor anything about "recent". I didn't like this answer anyway, because what if I'm trying to find the address of an old message's sender?

Answer (score 6):

An easy way I found to see the original email address is to reply to the message and scroll down in the new message until you see the original *quoted* message. It should start with something like:

> On Mar 30, 2019, at 11:38 PM, John Doe <j.doe@example.com> wrote:

The email address is between the < and > characters. If you don't really want to reply, just touch "Cancel" to dismiss the new email.

As pointed out below by [youcantryreachingme](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/163666/youcantryreachingme), this only works for the sender. If you have multiple email addresses associated with the same email account, it will not reveal the address that the email came in on.

I found an alternative approach though that does appear to show everything:

1. View the message
2. Touch reply button
3. In the action sheet scroll down to Print
4. In the Printer Options screen use the two-finger zoom gesture on the image of the email
5. In the new preview view, you should see all of the email addresses taken from the original email

[image]

Comment: That only works to find the sender's email address. It does not show the recipient email address.

Comment: You got me started in the right direction. I've posted an updated answer for the current (sad) state of iOS.

Answer (score 2):

OK, for a more complete solution (including other recipients) tested on iOS 15.3.1:

1. Reply All
2. Tap the "To:" or "Cc:" fields' names until (3 times, once to focus the message header area, again to highlight the name, and finally once more to show the complete email address) the email is displayed below the row
3. Delete draft

*Editorial: Apple really needs to fix this. For all the harping on security they do, they don't even allow me to easily verify the addresses of my emails!? Sending a personal email to a work address could be easily considered "insecure".*